# How to Extract a Division from Html with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the 'meanings' section of a dictionary entry from a html file using beautifulsoup but it is giving me some trouble. Here is a summary of what I have tried so far:

- I right click on the dictionary entry page below and save the webpage to my Python directory as 'aufmachen.html'

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufmachen

- Within the source code of this webpage, the section that I am trying to extract starts from line 1042 with the expression

- I wrote the code below but neither tags nor Bedeutungen contains any search results.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("aufmachen.html",encoding="utf8") as f:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(f,"html.parser")


tags = doc.body.findAll(text = '<div class="division "  id="bedeutungen">')

print(tags)

Bedeutungen = doc.body.findAll("div", {"id": "bedeutungen"})

print(Bedeutungen)
```

Could you please help me with this problem?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Not reproducible, `Bedeutungen` contains what you're looking for https://replit.com/@Samathingamajig/NegligibleCrispPlanes#main.py . Seems to be an issue with how you're loading the HTML. Also that's not what [`text="..."` is used for](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs:~:text=The%20string%20argument%20is%20new%20in%20Beautiful%20Soup%204.4.0.%20In%20earlier%20versions%20it%20was%20called%20text%3A)

Comment: Thank you so much! Once I resolve my first question, I was going to ask how to avoid having to save it as a html to my PC every time and load it automatically but I see you have already included that in your code.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then so you can mark this resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main bug in your code is that you send BS a file, not a string. Call `.read()` on your file to get a string.

```py
with open("aufmachen.html", "r",encoding="utf8") as f:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),"html.parser")
```

However it seems you want to pull in the HTML file from a URL, not a file on your computer. This can be done like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufmachen"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

Bedeutungen = soup.body.findAll("div", {"id": "bedeutungen"})

print(Bedeutungen)
```

Your first call to `.findAll()` didn't work because the `text` kwarg looks for text inside the tag, not a tag itself. The following works, but there's no particular reason to use this over the other shown above.

```py
tags = soup.body.findAll("div", class_="division", id="bedeutungen")
```